# I am working on an Angular project, and one of my service files suddenly grayed out in VS code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, angular10

I am working on an Angular project, and one of my service files suddenly grayed out in VS code. I checked in google for similar cases, and it says that files meant to be ignored from git are usually grayed out. But, I am not working with git, and neither is this file included in .gitignore file.

My code is still working fine, but I am still not sure how and why this file got grayed out. Is it something I need to check?

What should I do? I am not much used to VisualStudio Code and pretty new to Angular too.

[image: File Grayed out]

Comment: Pretty sure it means that its ignored like you said.  Even if you don't have a git repo, I believe VS Code tries to make one (even just a local one for it). If you right click on a file in the file explorer there is a context menu item for adding to .gitignore.  Its possible you accidentally clicked that?

Comment: Hi @cjd82187 I am not sure,if that happened; but deleting the temporary .gitignore file did solve the issue.